# How to store a queue of requests in an idiomatic Scala/FP way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

As the title says, I'm trying to store some commands in the program I'm writting (a code generator), only to interpret them at a later stage.

This is mainly due to fact that some commands needs information from others, and I think it would be nicer from my part not to force a very strict order on the command senders (though this choise also has the drawback of making it harder to decide wether a command is vadid or not).

The question is a very simple one: in Scala, I can't think of any other collection to represent this command queue except for the Buffer. Concurrency is not needed in my case, and it just feels silly to use immutable collections that are updated one element at a time.

I would like on the other hand to reduce mutability as much as possible in my program anyway - is this a place where it can be done resonably? Or is my intuition correct and Buffer is a natural fit for my case..

This is a sketch of how this store would look like if an immutable collection were used. (a termination command would say that we're done updating for a given symbol, which can then be constructed by interpreting its unique BuildCommand together with zero or more UpdateCommands )

```
trait Outcome
sealed trait Command {
  def symId : String
}
sealed trait ChangeCommand extends Command
sealed trait BuildCommand extends Command
sealed trait UpdateCommand extends Command
final case class TerminationCommand(symId: String) extends Command

var comQueue = immutable.Seq[ChangeCommand]()

private def translate(sId : String) : Outcome = {
  val forSymb = comQueue filter {_.symId}
  //...
}

def interpret(c : Command) = c match {
  case cc : ChangeCommand    => 
    comQueue = comQueue + cc
    None
  case TerminationCommand(s) =>
    Some(translate(s))
}
```

Comment: I must point out that most immutable collections do not copy the whole thing when you append, they share a lot of data (which they can, because everything is immutable).  Do some profiling before writing them off.  I like Vector.

Comment: @experquisite efficiency is not my primary concern here. I mainly said 'if feels silly' because an immutable collection would involve using an ugly var. And there would be a lot of  intermediate collections created (lightwheight or not) which gives me some feeling of wastefulness

Comment: It would only involve a var if you were doing an imperative loop?  It sounds like you could do an unfold into an immutable Seq?

Comment: @experquisite okay, I've edited the post and added some code (sorry all if my question was too dry without it). Can you avoid the var here? Commands come one at a time (e.g. 'set array x value to 5')

Comment: Why couldn't you have `interpret(Seq[ChangeCommand], Command) => (Seq[ChangeCommand], Option[Outcome])` 

Then you wouldn't have any state in here at all, and as a bonus, it'd be really easy to unit test.

Comment: @experquisite thanks for taking the time to  suggest, but that would mean, as far as I can tell, that the caller of `interpret` has to maintain the Seq[ChangeCommand]? Since commands come one at time, the call site will still have the same issue of the `var immutable.Seq`

Comment: Yes, there are inherent advantages to pushing state outwards, in my opinion. This really seems to be stream computation, so you might get more mileage out of RXScala or akka streams or scalaz streams....

Comment: I will have to agree with you wrt to state being moved to higher level components; for my case testing both the interpreter or its caller will be easier. Thanks for the hints - i'll go for the `Buffer` that gets processed as `immutable.Seq` for now as I'm just very few days away from my first Scala release ever ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `Seq` seems like a good fit.

You can start with a mutable `Buffer` to append the commands before converting into an immutable `Seq`.

Comment: storing intermediate stuff into a `Buffer` until it 'matures' and then gets processed as an immutable `Seq` seemed the most straight forward approach. Although I agree my interpreter would even better if it were stateless, this is what I'll use for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have append only operations and then you access them sequentially, I can't think of a better fit than an immutable List. Just use `Seq()`.

Comment: Not that it invalidates your point, but the commands will not be accessed sequencially. Instead, related commands will be clustered by applying `filter` or `find` operations and then interpreted together. I think I will go for the mutable for accumulation and immutable for processing, justified a bit by my comment on the initial post. I do consider your answer as a perfectly valid one, though